# Почему "приёмный покой"?

Tags: употребление-слов

Находясь в больнице, прочёл надпись - **приёмный покой**. Интересно, почему приёмное отделение назвали **покоем**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Покой `***Толковый словарь Ефремовой`
 ***1. м. 1) а) Состояние относительной неподвижности, отсутствия движения. б) перен. Состояние растения, при котором приостанавливается его рост. 2) Отсутствие движения и шума; тишина. 3) а) перен. Отсутствие волнений, сомнений, забот и т.п.; спокойствие. б) Бездействие. 2. м. устар.*** Жилая комната в доме**.* 3. м.** Название буквы древней славянской или старой русской азбуки.**

Вероятно, в значении "КОМНАТА для приёма больных" используется это выражение.

Comment: Смысл слова покой понятен, от того и делается непонятным это словосочетание. Но, благодаря вашему ответу, я пришёл к выводу, что покой здесь используется в качестве синонима "спокойствию". Ведь по сути-то больница это то место, где успокаивают боль. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Покой - это помещение, где соблюдается тишина.

Покоем (покоями) называют жилое помещение, комнату в большом доме, дворце, которые предназначены для отдыха, сна. Внутренние, женские, личные покои. | Светлые, полутёмные покои. | Войти, удалиться в покои. | Боярские, царские, княжеские покои.

МНЕНИЕ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА. "Не случайно, раньше жилые комнаты называли «покоями». И в этом - главное отличие господского дома от шалмана лихой харчевни. Не в каждом доме есть свои «покои». Их очень сложно создать. Я бы даже сказала так: если у вас есть покои, значит, вы правильно организовали свою жизнь".